# Tikzcd vertical bar error

Tags: tikz-cd

When I put a vertical bar "|" in a tikz-cd cell, for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
|A|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

then I get the error

```
 Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
```

What causes this error? Is this a bug or is it by design?

Placing curly braces around the vertical bars seems to fix this, so by replacing `|A|` by `{|A|}`. But it could become tedious when there are a lot of vertical bars. Is there a better workaround?

Comment: The bar character `|` is used to escape to tikz options. The expected syntax is `|[red]| X_1`. To avoid the confusion, write `{|X|}`.

Comment: BTW, welcome. And very good minimal working example.

Comment: @Symbol1 Welcome back! I did not see you in a long time.

Comment: @kiwi. Didn't see that you don't like the idea of `{|A|}`. Try `\makeatletter \let\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@normal@start@cell \makeatother`.
@Dr Was working on my doctoral thesis and will move to UCSD really soon.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks for the reply. I am close to San Francisco (94040 Mountain View). Let me know if you are in the area :).

Answer (score 3):

Do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@normal@start@cell
\makeatother
\begin{tikzcd}
|A|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

## Why it works?

TikZ-cd is implemented by a `\matrix...;` command
so everything boils down to how TikZ parses a `\matrix`.
At the beginning of every cell
`\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell` is executed.
It will first check if it sees a vertical bar `|`.

```
% tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex line 28-29
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar|{\tikz@lib@matrix@with@options}%
                      {\tikz@lib@matrix@normal@start@cell}}%
```

All you need to do is to tell TikZ not to check for `|`.
This can be done by letting `start@cell` to be `normal@start@cell`
the command that should be executed if there were no bar.